# Knockout text binding showing the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to text bind one element to a paragraph tag. It's not working properly and not giving any error in Browser. I am using Visual Studio for development.
I created a fiddle for showing the problem and there i got the error that my binding is not defined.

```
    function checking(obj)
{
    var self = this;    
    self.check = ko.observable(obj.count);
    alert(self.check());
};

function MyVM()
{
    var self = this;    
    self.MyArr = ko.observableArray();        
    var myObj = {count: 4};

    self.function1 = function(){

       self.MyArr.push(new checking(myObj));        
    };

    self.function1();

}

ko.applyBindings(new MyVM(), document.getElementById('myId'));
```

My HTML:

```
<div id = "myId">
    <p data-bind="text: check"></p>
</div>
```

i know if i define the check field in MyVM() then it will work but i want to use the check field from the cheking(obj). What will be the right way to achieve this.

Here is the link
http://jsfiddle.net/6ymx8vja/

Comment: because `check` is inside observableArray . try this http://jsfiddle.net/6ymx8vja/1/ . cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try constructing view as similar to viewModel

**View:**

```
<div data-bind="foreach:MyArr">
    <p data-bind="text: check"></p>
</div>
```

**viewModel:**

```
function checking(obj)
{
    var self = this;    
    self.check = ko.observable(obj.count);
};

function MyVM()
{
    var self = this;    
    self.MyArr = ko.observableArray();        
    var myObj = {count: 4};
    self.function1 = function(){
       self.MyArr.push(new checking(myObj)); //your `check` is present inside observableArray so you need to get hold of observableArray to access its inside content      
    };
    self.function1();
}
ko.applyBindings(new MyVM());
```

working fiddle up **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/6ymx8vja/1/)**

well if dont want to use `foreach` in view you can directly access via index
like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/6ymx8vja/2/)**

Comment: Thank you i understood the concept now !